# How to Install FCKEditor in YetAnotherForum

Tags: fckeditor

I want to install FCK editor in latest Yaf(yetanotherforum.net) but the instructions I found in Yaf forums are not correct or not for the latest forum release of them.

Could some body give me the working instructions if they did the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need an expert on two quite rare technologies - your chances are not good to get a quick answer.

Comment: I see, I thing it'd be a little hard to find usable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of guidance can be found here [Custom Editors with YAF](http://forum.yetanotherforum.net/default.aspx?g=posts&t=452)

Comment: I did walk through that page already. Nothing special and working there.

Comment: 1) Download File http://superb-east.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/fckeditor/FCKeditor.Net_2.6.3.zip
2) Copy FCKeditor.Net_2.6.3\bin\Release\2.0\FredCK.FCKeditorV2.dll to yaf\bin (Or more formally, add the project reference properly in Visual Studio)
3) Select FCKEditor in the drop down. All your support files (like plugins) will go in yaf/editors/FCKEditorV2/

I am not 100% sure of the details as it has been a while since I have worked on yaf source code. You can see for yourself in the source code: YetAnotherForum.NET/App_Code/YAF/ForumEditor.cs
Good luck.